# Problem in Printing Friggeri Resume/CV

Tags: fonts, fontspec, printing, cv, friggeri-cv

I am using Friggeri Resume/CV template, which can be found [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv). *This template is absolutely beautiful and easy to read on a computer. Its look is astounding and I just like it very much.* However, those which have `Helvetica Neue UltraLigh` as their fonts are not printed nicely and are very difficult to read although the printer setting is 600 dpi.

```
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
```

The print option of the class does not help at all and it only removes colors from this template for printing:

```
\documentclass[print]{friggeri-cv}
```

Could someone kindly help me find a better replacement for `Helvetica Neue UltraLight` which is more printer-friendly? Something a little bit thicker such that it can be seen better in a print while still having a contrast compared to `Helvetica Neue` and `Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Helvetica Neue Thin (or Condensed Thin)

Comment: @erik Go  ahead, make it an official answer. A few screenshot for comparison would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica Neue has several weights, so changing from UltraLight to Thin will preserve the style while increasing readability/printability. The image below compares `\setmainfont[Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}` (left) with `\setmainfont[Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Thin}` (right)

[image]